# REST using Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a REST service project in java with name RESTServ using Spring but I am not able to run it.
I am using **Wildfly 8.1 , JDK 1.8 and Spring - 4.2**

This is my User Bean:

```
package com.rest.service;

public class User {

    private int userid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    public int getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userid=" + userid + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

This is my Service Controller:

```
package com.rest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.rest.dao.UserService;
import com.rest.service.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/")
public class SpringServiceController {

    UserService userService = new UserService();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        return user;
    }
}
```

I have created DBUtility and User Service files to get data from the database.
This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>RESTServ</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

And this is my rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rest.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

When I am trying to access the REST service through URL deployed on WildFly 8.1 - **localhost:8080/RESTServ/user** or **localhost:8080/RESTServ/user/1** it shows following error:

```
Context Path:/RESTServ
Servlet Path:
Path Info:/user
Query String:null
Stack Trace
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong...Can anyone help me as I am new to this concept?

Comment: try to add a id after `localhost:8080/RESTServ/user/`

Comment: You have not given Id in url assume user id is 1 than your request will be like localhost:8080/RESTServ/user/1

Comment: I have tried appending id still problem persists.

Comment: Also, you have two slashes: `/user/` and `/{id}`. Use `/user`. And the servlet is named `rest` but you're mapping `mvc-dispatcher` instead, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I corrected that now it throws org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

Well, `localhost:8080/RESTServ/user` is not mapped in you controller, only `localhost:8080/RESTServ/user/{id}` is. So you need to add this resource:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Iterable<User> getUsers() {
    return userService.listAll();
}
```

Also your `@RequestMapping` on the class should be `@RequestMapping("/user")` (without the slash at the end).

---

By the way, it is not really relevant here, but I'm pretty sure that `UserService` is meant to be autowired.